# Why doesn't Meteor.user() work inside publish functions?

Tags: security, meteor

Mainly out of curiosity, but also for a better understanding of Meteor security, what is the reason(ing) behind `Meteor.user()` not working inside publish functions?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The reason is in this piece of code (from meteor source code)

```
Meteor.user = function () {
    var userId = Meteor.userId();
    if (!userId)
        return null;
        return Meteor.users.findOne(userId);
};
Meteor.userId = function () {
    // This function only works if called inside a method. In theory, it
    // could also be called from publish statements, since they also
    // have a userId associated with them. However, given that publish
    // functions aren't reactive, using any of the infomation from
    // Meteor.user() in a publish function will always use the value
    // from when the function first runs. This is likely not what the
    // user expects. The way to make this work in a publish is to do
    // Meteor.find(this.userId()).observe and recompute when the user
    // record changes.
    var currentInvocation = DDP._CurrentInvocation.get();
    if (!currentInvocation)
        throw new Error("Meteor.userId can only be invoked in method calls. Use   this.userId in publish functions.");
        return currentInvocation.userId;
};
```